# Reasonable message length to be stored in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle, memory-efficient

I have a complex process that interacts with multiple systems.

Each of these systems may produce error messages that I would like to store in a table of my Oracle database (note that I have statuses but the nature of the process is such that the errors may not always be predefined).

We are talking about hundred thousands of transactions each day where 1% may result in various errors.

1) Wanted to know what is a reasonable/acceptable length for the database field and how big of a message should I be storing?

2) Memory wise, does it really matter how large the field is defined in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reasonable" and "acceptable" depends on the application.  Assuming that you want to define the database column as a `VARCHAR2` rather than a `CLOB`, and assuming that you aren't using 12.1 or later, you can declare the column to hold up to 4000 bytes.  Is that enough for whatever error messages you need to support?  Is there a lower limit on the length of an error message that you can establish?  If you're producing error messages that are designed to be shown to a user, you're probably going to be generating shorter messages.  If you're producing and storing stack traces, you may need to declare the column as a `CLOB` because 4000 bytes may not be sufficient.

What sort of memory are we talking about?  On disk, a `VARCHAR2` will only allocate the space that is actually required to store the data.  When the block is read into the buffer cache, it will also only use the space required to store the data.  If you start allocating local variables in PL/SQL, depending on the size of the field, Oracle may allocate more space than is required to store the particular data for that local variable in order to try to avoid the cost of growing and shrinking the allocation when you modify the string.  If you return the data to a client application (including a middle tier application server), that client may allocate a buffer in memory based on the maximum size of the column rather than based on the actual size of the data.

Comment: what would be the benefit of using `VARCHAR2` vs `CLOB`.
More details:
I am not going to be querying on this field.
Using oracle 12 and later.
How many characters would 4000 bytes translate to? I was thinking something more than 500. 
We are talking about Flash Memory.

Comment: @otc - A `CLOB` is potentially less efficient to deal with than a `VARCHAR2` but allows you to potentially store multiple PB of information in a single row.  If you are using 12.1 or later, it is possible to enable the database to store 32000 bytes of information in a `VARCHAR2` column.  Since you're worried about the space taken on disk, a `VARCHAR2` will only use the space actually required for the data in question.